# I need to add local storage to my to do list and I'm clueless

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am working on a to do list for a final project in school.  I have the list itself set up and working but I forgot to add local storage so that when the page is refreshed it keeps the values that the user set up, like deleting list items or adding new ones. 1) I don't know where in my code to insert it and 2) I don't know the format, like "this variable that I already used goes here" type thing.  I pasted the code to codepen and it can be found here: https://codepen.io/otterspawdesign/pen/bJXaYm
this is the javascript:

```
var listitems = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < listitems.length; i++) {
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  listitems[i].appendChild(span);
}

var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
  close[i].onclick = function() {
    var div = this.parentElement;
    div.style.display = "none";
  }
}

var list = document.querySelector('ul');
list.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName === 'li') {
    ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
  }
}, false);

function newElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("typefield").value;
  var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(t);
  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("Type an item to add to your list.");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("thelist").appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById("typefield").value = "";

  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  li.appendChild(span);

  for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].onclick = function() {
      var div = this.parentElement;
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
  }

}
```

I'm on a tight deadline (tonight at midnight) so if someone can explain it to me like I'm 5 years old and provide me with code and tell me how it works, i mean step by step, I will be so so grateful.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: I did that, and while I understand what it does, I'm not sure where to implement it in my code. Also, do I use variables that I've already declared?

Comment: Your code has some sort of data you want to persist.  Any time that changes, set the new value on localStorage.  When the page reloads, thus a load event happens, or the document ready, which ever you like, check if that value exists in the localStorage.  If it does, restore your data on the page.

Comment: Keeping in mind that **data** does not refer to the html.  It refers to the information the html presents.  You use that data to recreate the html.

Comment: So if I'm understanding what you are saying, I would implement local storage on the variable "listitems"?

Comment: `listItems` is a list of li elements.  That's the html.  Your list items have text that is displayed to the user.  **That** is the data.  Storing that data as a stringified array of some sort, will allow you to retrieve it on page refresh and rebuild the html from that data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var Todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos')) || [];

for (var i = 0; i < Todos.length; i++) {
  newElementFromLocalStorage(Todos[i])
}
```

This is the trick. The first line of code needs to go at the top of your javascript. It returns either an array of the todos from your localstorage or an empty array when the localstorage is empty (first load). The for loop will then perform a function on all these todo's.

The only thing you need to do (pun intended) is write the `newElementFromLocalStorage` function. A function that takes a string, and creates a new element from it.

```js
Todos.push(newTodo);

localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(Todos));
```

These lines of code need to be included in the `newElement` function. The first line pushes a new todo to the todo's array (or the empty array, which will then become the todo's). The second line of code sets the localstorage to the new 'state' with the newly added todo.

In these lines of code the `newTodo` variable is not declared, that's something you need to do (oh yes, another one). It should just be the string you read from the input.

I realize this is a schoolproject, but I do want to mention that for an actual application like this you wouldn't use local storage, you would connect a database. Hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: @MelissaKemp Good you found an answer to your question! If it helped you, please mark it (the little tick left to the answer) as the answer that helped you out.

Comment: Yes, would be nice

Comment: Hey @MelissaKemp, I noticed you deleted the comment stating this helped your problem. Did it not work after all?

Comment: hmmm, no this helped me, i don't recall deleting the comment, what the heck?